# jQuery length function not working correclty in checkbox field

Tags: jquery, checkbox, string-length

I am trying to use jQuery in a checkbox field  to calculate the number of fields that have been checked, but I don't seem to have got the syntax correct.

Below is my attempt to count the number of fields that have been checked (there are over 20 checkbox fields).

```
$('#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]').click(function()
  if($('#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]').length == $('#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        }
  else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
```

I think that the fault lies in my DOM selection.

The checkboxes are stored in a table with an **id** of **product-effect-table**

Below is a sample of the table and an input bar;

```
 <table id="product-effect-table">
   <td>  <input type="checkbox" name="effect5" id="effect5" value="1" checked="checked"       product_effect_id="5" /></td>
</table>
```

Comment: hi everyone. very sorry for the above question. it has now been resolved.

Comment: That's great! Then provide how do you resolve it, it could help other people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SVP6J/)

mismatched `{}` you forgot to add  brace(`{`) `.click(function () {`

```
$('#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    if ($('#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]').length == $('#product-effect-table input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Suggested By [**roasted**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/roasted)

[**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is preferred over `.attr()`

so you can make use of `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

like this :-
`.prop('checked',true)` and `.prop('checked',false)`

Comment: .prop() is the prefered method

Comment: ty i added you suggestion in the answer .

Comment: Thx for update! To be more specific, it is `.prop('checked',true)` and `.prop('checked',false)` and don't use `.removeProp('checked')`

Comment: i made a typo, extra " ' " for .prop('checked',true'<<- here)